# Is being able to vote on Community wiki posts a bug?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, voting

I was just looking at [This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25564/when-should-you-call-yourself-a-senior-developer) and I hovered over the voting buttons, and then a title showed "This answer is useful" (or whatever that sentence be), and the mouse cursor was a pointer, so I just clicked and the voting counter increased

Is this a bug? or what? the buttons are completely transparent but they are clickable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upvote In Community Wiki](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1358/upvote-in-community-wiki)

Comment: This isn't a bug. Say you have 5 answers that are Community Wiki. Without voting how would the community mark the best one?

Comment: @Oded Well why the buttons are hidden then?

Comment: No Idea. I can see them, even when browsing anonymously. Probably something in your setup?

Comment: @Oded oh, that's so weird. I use the latest Chrome with the latest browsing-related stuff here, I think this is a bug then

Comment: I too am using latest Chrome... try to disable all extensions/plug-ins/add-ons and see if things start working. Perhaps provide more info about your OS/Browser (and try other browsers)?

Comment: @Oded oh, that's so weird, I disabled my ad blocker and it worked. Don't know why it was blocking the buttons, pretty weird.

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't like SVG images.

Comment: My corporate laptop's proxy will sometimes decide to disable javascript and one of the things that goes away are vote buttons.